# Call the first <span> in a scrollbar when press enter using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a text box which is using for search.When enter the characters it searches the values and shows one by one in a scrollbar. When i click on any found value it redirects to the related page but when press enter it should call first value in that scrollbar.Below is my code.

```
<div><input type="text" value="" placeholder="search" ng-model="searchText" name="testName" ng-keyup="search()"></div>
    <div class="scroll" ng-show="searchText.length" ng-hide="!searchText.length">
    <div ng-repeat="relatedData in data">
        <span ng-click="showDetails(relatedData)" ng-model="searchText">{{ relatedData }} </span><br />
    </div>
    </div>
```

and below is my script code:

```
$scope.showDetails = function(relatedData) {
            $http.get("searchInfo.json").success(function(response) {
var searchT = relatedData;
$http.get(searchT+'Details.json').success(function(response) {
            $scope.details = response;
            $scope.searchText = "";
        });
});
}
```

Could you please help to call first  value in multiple values scrollbar,Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I don't think `ng-model` does anything when used on a `<span>`... Your `{{relatedData}}` binding should suffice to populate the `<span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to wrap your search field in a form element:

```
<form ng-submit="showDetails(data[0])">
    <input type="text" 
        value=""
        placeholder="search"
        ng-model="searchText"
        name="testName"
        ng-keyup="search()">
</form>
```

ng-submit will catch the form submit event triggered by pressing Enter.

Comment: No problem. If this answer has solved your problem, would you please accept it as the solution?